# Void System.Threading.Monitor.Enter Error when using ILMerge

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ilmerge

I'm trying to use ILMerge to combine my C# program with 3 referenced DLL's. If I run the program without merging them, everything runs well but when I merge them I get the `"Void System.Threading.Monitor.Enter"` Error.

Here are the DLL's I am combining:

```
HTMLAgilityPack.dll
MySql.Data.dll
RKLib.ExportData.dll
```

The error appears to be coming from the `MySql.Data.dll` but I am not really sure why it would throw this exception.

Any ideas much appreciated.

EDIT:  Full error I am receiving is:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(System.Object, Boolean ByRef)'.
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString) in :line 0
```

Comment: Always add the full error information. Makes it easier to find similar errors.

Comment: Monitor.Enter(Object, Boolean%) was added in .NET 4.0. Does the merged assembly reference the .NET 4.x assemblies or perhaps an older version?

Comment: Could you tell me how to check that?  I know my program is but I'm not sure how to check if MySql.Data is.

Comment: It seems ILMerge targets .NET 3.5 by default if you don't use the target platform option to point to your v4 framework directory.

Comment: Well that was Easy!  Thanks for your help.  If you add as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of the framework are you using? There is a targetplatform option you may need to set if you are using 4.0/4.5 for example.

`/targetplatform:version,platformdirectory`